# Sending sensitive information against AD

Tags: vb.net, security, authentication, active-directory

I am working on vb.net 2.0 application which checks users credential against AD by sending LDAP configuration, user name, and password to DirectoryEntry method. LDAP is configured in web.config file. An AppScan result is showing that login request was not sent over SSL and recommends always using SSL and POST (body) parameters when sending sensitive information:

```
DirectoryEntry("LDAPPath"), txtUserName, txtPassword)
```

How can I send this request against AD in a secure way?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the AuthenticationType on your `DirectoryEntry` to `AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer` this should start working over LDAPS..